# Railstutorial: Integration Tests for Activated Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I’ve been going through the Railstutorial and am curious about the “Extra Credit” for the second exercise of [Chapter 10](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation_password_reset). Searching around, I came across this other [StackOverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30855953/railstutorial-ch-10-how-do-i-test-that-only-activated-users-are-viewable-to-ot). I follow the logic provided by the questioner, so I’m also perplexed why they’re getting the failure.

I replicated the original questioner’s work & subsequent failure, but the only answer provided does not fix the problem - it actually yields an error (also, `domain_scope` isn’t broached as a subject until the following chapter).

I’d comment on either the the question or the answer but unfortunately I don’t have the reputation for either - and I didn’t want to abuse the answer feature to share this “Me too!”.

With all due respect to the original questioner, here’s the code in question (copied from the original question)

## users_controller.rb

```
def index
  @users = User.where(activated: true).paginate(page: params[:page])
end

def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to root_url and return unless @user.activated?
end
```

## Integration test in users_index_test.rb

```
test "only show profiles of activated users" do
  log_in_as(@admin)
  get users_path
  assert_template 'users/index'
  assert_select 'div.pagination'
  first_page_of_users = User.paginate(page: 1)
  first_page_of_users.each do |user|
    assert_equal true, user.activated?
  end
end
```

## A non-activated user in users.yml

```
non:
  name: Non Activated
  email: nonactivated@example.gov
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  activated: false
```

## Subsequent test failure

```
FAIL["test_only_show_profiles_of_activated_users", UsersIndexTest, 2015-08-12 12:45:43 -0700]
test_only_show_profiles_of_activated_users#UsersIndexTest (1439408743.76s)
  Expected: true
    Actual: false
test/integration/users_index_test.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersIndexTest>'
test/integration/users_index_test.rb:33:in `block in <class:UsersIndexTest>'
```

## ‘domain-scope’ suggested answer in users_index_test.rb

```
test "only show profiles of activated users" do
  log_in_as(@admin)
  get users_path
  assert_template 'users/index'
  assert_select 'div.pagination'
  first_page_of_users = User.paginate(page: 1)
  first_page_of_users.each do |user|
    default_scope where(:published => true)
  end
end
```

## Subsequent test error

```
ERROR["test_only_show_profiles_of_activated_users", UsersIndexTest, 2015-08-12 12:45:44 -0700]
 test_only_show_profiles_of_activated_users#UsersIndexTest (1439408744.71s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `where' for #<UsersIndexTest:0x007faf7aa91d80>
    test/integration/users_index_test.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersIndexTest>'
    test/integration/users_index_test.rb:33:in `block in <class:UsersIndexTest>'
  test/integration/users_index_test.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersIndexTest>'
  test/integration/users_index_test.rb:33:in `block in <class:UsersIndexTest>'
```

I’ve since tried an alternate integration test which also fails:

```
def setup
  @admin          = users(:michael)
  @non_admin      = users(:foo)
  @non_activated  = users(:non)
end

test "only show profiles of activated users" do
  log_in_as(@admin)
  get users_path
  assert_template 'users/index'
  assert_select 'div.pagination'
  first_page_of_users = User.paginate(page: 1)
  first_page_of_users.each do |user|
    assert_not user_path(@non_activated)
  end
end
```

## Failure

```
FAIL["test_only_show_profiles_of_activated_users", UsersIndexTest, 2015-08-12 12:45:43 -0700]
test_only_show_profiles_of_activated_users#UsersIndexTest (1439408743.72s)
  Expected "/users/895943698" to be nil or false
  test/integration/users_index_test.rb:35:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersIndexTest>'
  test/integration/users_index_test.rb:34:in `block in <class:UsersIndexTest>’
```

These failures appear to indicate that the change in code to the `index` action in `users_controller.rb` isn’t working - but I’ve confirmed from manual testing that it is.

Any help most appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I was working on this too.  I think I found your problem.

In your test, you pull up the first page of Users with the code:

```
first_page_of_users = User.paginate(page: 1)
```

When you check this for inactive users, this gives you an error because one of the entries in your Users database is inactive.  You never left it out of your array.

I think you could fix this by using this line to include the "where activated" condition.

```
first_page_of_users = User.where(activated: true).paginate(page: 1)
```

But I didn't like this solution, because it doesn't check the index as much as runs the same search as you wrote in your users_controller.

Here's my solution, which I wrapped into my "index as admin including pagination" test:

```
User.paginate(page: 1).each do |user|
  if user.activated?
    assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), text: user.name
    unless user == @admin
      assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), text: 'delete'
    end
  else
    assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), text: user.name, count: 0
  end
end
```

Here's how it works:  It pulls up the first page of Users, and if the user is activated, it looks for a link to the user as well as a delete button.  If the user isn't activated, it checks to make sure the user isn't displayed.

Comment: I like this solution the best for exactly the reason you stated. Nice job!

Answer (score 2):

I came to essentially the same solution as Mickey (and upvoted his solution) except I used a slightly different implementation of assert_select:

```
User.paginate(page: 1).each do |user|
  if user.activated?
    assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), text: user.name
    unless user == @admin
      assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), text: 'delete'
    end
  else
    assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), false
  end
end
```

My understanding of this use of assert_select is to make sure there are no anchor elements that have a href containing the user_path of the unactivated user.  This is essentially the same as making sure the count of the number of anchor elements having a href with the user_path is zero (Mickey's solution).  The test suite liked both versions.

This and Mikey's answer applies to the first part of the extra-credit, i.e. *Write integration test for /users.*  For the second part of the extra-credit, i.e. *Write integration test for **/users/:id***, I did the following:

First I made a new integration test (see footnote for why):

```
rails generate integration_test users_show
```

Then I updated **app/controllers/users_controller.rb** as the OP did and made an unactivated user in **test/fixtures/users.yml**.

**app/controllers/users_controller.rb:**

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to root_url and return unless @user.activated?
end
```

**test/fixtures/users.yml:**

```
.
.
.
archer:
  name: Sterling Archer
  email: duchess@example.gov
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  activated: true
  activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>

lana:
  name: Lana Kane
  email: hands@example.gov
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  activated: false
```

Lastly, I added the `@unactivated_user` and a new test to automatically-generated **test/integration/users_show_test.rb**:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersShowTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def setup
    @unactivated_user = users(:lana)
    @activated_user   = users(:archer)
  end

  test "should redirect to root_url when user not activated" do
    log_in_as(@unactivated_user)
    assert_redirected_to root_url
  end

  test "should not redirect root_url when user is activated" do
    log_in_as(@activated_user)
    assert_redirected_to @activated_user
  end
end
```

My test suite was green after doing this.  I added the `@activated_user` and the second test just to make sure that it wasn't a fluke that the first test passed (since I'm really new at tests).

*FOOTNOTE: First I tried adding a test to **test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb**, but I soon understood that although this could work, it didn't meet the criterion of it being an *integration test* as specified in the extra-credit assignment, and it seemed to take an extra step to get it to work:

```
  test "should redirect to root_url when user not activated" do
    log_in_as(@unactivated_user)
    get :show, id: @unactivated_user
    assert_redirected_to root_url
  end
```

After I realized it probably should be an integration test rather than a controller test, I looked for an existing test file in which to place it.  Because users_edit_test, users_index_test, users_login_test, and users_signup_test didn't seem like a good fit for this test, I just created a new one.  Seems like it worked out ok.

Comment: Great solution to the second part of question 3! I like it a lot!

Answer (score 0):

sorry Anna but you got the "second part of the extra-credit"  wrong

the task was to build a test that make sure  logged-in user would'nt be able to see non activated user

the way you wrote your test (the second time) is that the unactivated user would try to view his own profile page 
(which will also redirect him to the root url but that is becouse every page un activated user is trying to access will redirect him to the root_url)

the test should be someting like that

```
require 'test_helper'



class UsersShowTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
    def setup
   @unactivated_user = users(:moshe)
   @activated_user   = users(:archer)
 end

   test "should only show activated users" do
    log_in_as (@activated_user)
  get user_path(@unactivated_user)
     assert_redirected_to root_url
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to add an unactivated user to the users.yml fixture, the users_index_test.rb test "index as admin including pagination and delete links" would fail with

> FAIL["test_index_as_admin_including_pagination_and_delete_links", UsersIndexTest, 1.7782473900006153]
>    test_index_as_admin_including_pagination_and_delete_links#UsersIndexTest (1.78s)
>           Expected at least 1 element matching "a[href="/users/659682706"]", found 0..
>           Expected 0 to be >= 1.
>           test/integration/users_index_test.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersIndexTest>'
>           test/integration/users_index_test.rb:17:in`block in '

I first tried to simply include the test for activated users in that test by adding

```
if user == @unactivated_user
assert_redirected_to root_url
else
<the original test code>
```

That produced an error of

> FAIL["test_index_as_admin_including_pagination_and_delete_links", UsersIndexTest, 1.7827676309971139]
>    test_index_as_admin_including_pagination_and_delete_links#UsersIndexTest (1.78s)
>           Expected response to be a <3XX: redirect>, but was a <200: OK>
>           test/integration/users_index_test.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersIndexTest>'
>           test/integration/users_index_test.rb:17:in`block in '

So I changed the if condition to simply true and added a separate test logged in as a non-admin, activated user.  This seems to work.  My users_index_test.rb in full:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersIndexTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @admin = users(:michael)
    @non_admin = users(:archer)
    @unactivated_user = users(:malory)
  end

  test "index as admin including pagination and delete links" do
    log_in_as(@admin)
    get users_path
    assert_template 'users/index'
    assert_select 'div.pagination', count: 2
    first_page_of_users = User.paginate(page: 1)
    first_page_of_users.each do |user|
      if user == @unactivated_user
        true
      else
        assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), text: user.name
          unless user == @admin
            assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), text: 'delete'
          end
      end
    end
    assert_difference 'User.count', -1 do
      delete user_path(@non_admin)
    end
  end
  #
  #   User.paginate(page:1).each do |user|
  #     assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), text: user.name
  #   end
  # end
  test "index as non-admin" do
    log_in_as(@non_admin)
    get users_path
    assert_select 'a', text: 'delete', count: 0
  end

  test "should only show activated users" do
    log_in_as(@non_admin)
    get user_path(@unactivated_user)
    assert_redirected_to root_url
  end

end
```

My users.yml:

```
# Read about fixtures at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html
#empty
michael:
  name: Michael Example
  email: michael@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  admin: true
  activated: true
  activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>

archer:
  name: Sterlin Archer
  email: duchess@example.gov
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  activated: true
  activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>

lana:
  name: Lana Kane
  email:  hands@example.gov
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  activated: true
  activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>

malory:
  name: Malory Archer
  email:  boss@example.gov
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  activated: false
  #activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>

<% 30.times do |n| %>
user_<%= n %>:
  name: <%= "User #{n}" %>
  email: <%= "user-#{n}@example.com" %>
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  activated: true
  activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>
  <% end %>
```

My users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user, only: :destroy

  def index
    @users = User.where(activated: true).paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to root_url and return unless @user.activated?
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user= User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    #@user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      #sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User deleted"
    redirect_to users_path
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

  # Before filters

  # Confirms a logged-in user
  def logged_in_user
    unless logged_in?
      store_location
      flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
      redirect_to login_url
    end
  end

  # Confirms the correct user.
  def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
  end

  #Confirms an admin user
  def admin_user
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.try(:admin?)
  end



end
```

Hope my solution helps someone.

Comment: Please split this into the answer proper and the additional question, and ask your follow-up question by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button; you will probably want to include a link to this one for context.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - edited out the question but left my process of arriving at the answer in place as that is probably more helpful than just the final code.

Comment: Yes, that's reasonable. You might be able to trim a little more (in particular, commented-out code), but you have a good basis here.

Answer (score 0):

Also had a problem with this integration test. 
**Don't forget to set at least 1 user in fixtures "Activated = false"**
My short solution, hope it helps someone
**Users.yml**

```
michael:
    name: Michael Example
    email: michael@example.com
    password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
    admin: true
    activated: true
    activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>


  archer:
    name: Sterling Archer
    email: duchess@example.gov
    password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
    activated: false #do not forget to set at least 1 user activated to false
    activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>

  lana:
    name: Lana Kane
    email: hands@example.gov
    password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
    activated: true
    activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>

  malory:
    name: Malory Archer
    email: boss@example.gov
    password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
    activated: true
    activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>

  <% 30.times do |n| %>
  user_<%= n %>:
    name:  <%= "User #{n}" %>
    email: <%= "user-#{n}@example.com" %>
    password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
    activated: true
    activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>
  <% end %>
```

only check "that non-activated users aren't showing"

**users_index_test.rb**

```
class UsersIndexTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
    def setup
      @admin     = users(:michael)
      @non_admin = users(:lana)
    end
    test 'display only activated users' do
      log_in_as(@non_admin)
      get users_path
      first_page_of_users = User.where(activated: false).paginate(page: 1)
      first_page_of_users.each do |user|
        assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), text: user.name, count: 0
      end
    end

  end
```

don't forget to change **users_controller.rb** for test correctness

```
    def index 
      # @users = User.where(activated: true).paginate(page: params[:page])        
      @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end
```

this way you able to check that test works correctly

**ADD** to not brake an oldest test index as admin including pagination and delete links
add **where(activated = true)** as showing below

```
     test 'index as admin including pagination and delete links' do
      log_in_as(@admin)
      get users_path
      assert_template 'users/index'
      assert_select 'div.pagination'
      first_page_of_users = User.where(activated: true).paginate(page: 1)
      first_page_of_users.each do |user|
        assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), text: user.name
        unless user == @admin
          assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), text: 'delete'
        end
      end
      assert_difference 'User.count', -1 do
        delete user_path(@non_admin)
      end
    end
```